# Переписать код common lisp без eval

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Переписать код common lisp без  eval:

```
(setf lst '(a b c) a 1 b 2 c 3)
(mapcar #'eval lst) => (1 2 3))
```

C **`,** не получается.
Зачем это надо - есть функция на вход которой подается квотированное математическое выражение, функция его преобразует в формулу latex. Затем на вход той же функции надо подать то же математическое выражение, но чтобы переменные вычислились в свое значение.

Comment: какой результат ожидается?

Comment: (dff lst) =>    nlst  =  (1 2 3)

Comment: Не так вместо определения функции просто выражение оставляю (mapcar #'eval nlst) => (1 2 3)

Comment: У меня получается только через другую переменную : `(mapcar #'eval lst) => (1 2 3)` При чём тут `nlst`?

Comment: Да ни при чем nlst, я туда раньше 1 2 3 писал, нужно как (mapcar #'eval lst) => (1 2 3) только без eval. Если б можно было вопрос отредактировать ...

Comment: Так там есть кнопка "править", под вопросом)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае для получения значения символов можно воспользоваться функцией [`symbol-value`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_symb_5.htm)

```
(mapcar #'symbol-value lst) => (1 2 3))
```

Comment: Технически все верно, ушел думать и переписывать код